# Is there a better way to write this line of C# code in C#3.0?

Tags: c#-3.0, properties, nullable

I have a property declared as follows:

```
public decimal? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

I am needing to pass this value to another method as a string and so the only way I see to do so is as follows:

```
MyProperty == null ? null : MyProperty.ToString()
```

This looks very messy when you have a number of similar properties being passed into a method.

Does anyone know if there is a better and more concise way of writing this?

Oh, and if anyone can think of a more appropriate title to this question please feel free to change it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `Nullable<T>.ToString()` [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx) ...

```
var s = MyProperty.ToString(); // returns "" if MyProperty is null
```

Comment: Wow, really? Have learnt something new.  I would never have tried that, thinking it would throw a null pointer exception

Comment: Wow! I had no idea .ToString still worked for a nullable value that was null. That's awesome!

Comment: ...But it sounds like the author wanted to have NULL if the value is NULL!!??

Comment: @Dmitriy: null == "" for strings in .NET

Comment: @Cameron, I believe it (null != "") in .NET. Check it in your code.
That is why we got string.IsNullOrEmpty method in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HasValue instead of the comparison:

```
MyProperty.HasValue ? MyProperty.Value.ToString() : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make string get properties on the class containing the property and it won't be messy wen you need to get the string version.

```
    public decimal? MyProperty { get; set; }

    public string MyPropertyString
    {
        get
        {
            return MyProperty.HasValue ? MyProperty.Value.ToString() : null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an extension method on Decimal.

```
public static string Str(this decimal? value)
{
    return value == null ? null : MyProperty.ToString()
}
```

You then call it like this:

```
MyProperty.Str()
```

Comment: No. Should be on decimal**?** (Nullable)

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to have zero istead of null then:

```
(MyProperty ?? 0).ToString()
```

Otherwise add extension method:

```
public static string AsString(this decimal? val)
{
    return val == null ? null : val.Value.ToString();
}

// Use:
MyProperty.AsString() // This will NEVER cause NullReferenceException
```